# How to start WebLogic in profiling mode?

Tags: weblogic, profiling

No information found for this. Is there any way to start weblogic in profiling mode? Or, maybe, it's activated by default?

Answer (score 3):

Profiling action can be initiated 2 ways

1) Pass the profiling action while you execute the startWeblogic.sh. Following parameters can be appended

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

2) The same parameters can be appended from startup tab in weblogic server

Comment: Thank you, Shailender, will try this. I've also found another solution - applying profilerinterface through java opts at weblogic startup and then connect with profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i got. Mainly focused on remote profiling using NetBeans

- generated remote profiling package for target OS and JVM architecture (32 or 64 bit) (Netbeans -> Profile -> Attach Profiler -> Change link, select OS and Java platform -> click "Create a remote profiling package" link)
- copy this package to target machine
- execute calibration script (calibrate.bat / calibrate.sh (chmod +x))
- add specific argument to java_otps with path to this package

> -agentpath:PathToProfilerPackage\lib\deployed\jdk16\windows-amd64\profilerinterface.dll=PathToProfilerPackage\lib,5140

- restart weblogic. Startup will be interrupted until remote profiler connected
- connect to a server using NetBeans profiler. Weblogic startup will continue.

However, i still can't download heap dump (which is available when attaching to local java.exe Weblogic process) but that's something.